# Android, Why doesn't it pass in my broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to use a broadcastReceiver to catch the headset button click with my android application but it doesn't seem to pass into my receiver class. I looked a large part of questions yet, but no working answers. Thank you.

PS : Sorry for my english ;)

Here's my mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        HeadsetReceiver r = new HeadsetReceiver();
        filter.setPriority(1000);
        registerReceiver(r, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver class :

```
public class HeadsetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String ACTION_BUTTON_HEADSET = "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BUTTON_HEADSET)){
            System.out.println("Just a test");
        }
    }
}
```

And my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver class="mypackage.HeadsetReceiver"
        android:name="mypackage.HeadsetReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to register your receiver the audio manager. You can do it in your onCreate of your activity:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(
    new ComponentName(this, HeadsetReceiver.class));
```

Also you can delete the IntentFilter code, as it is defined already in your manifest.